# Python, Changing Desktop Background from URL

Tags: python, background, desktop

I currently have this:

```
import ctypes

PATH = 'F:\Designs\Privat\Random Banner\Banner.png'
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, PATH, 3)
```

But now, I want to get the Image from a URL, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import urllib.request
import ctypes

URL = "https://www.google.gr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_160x56dp.png"

PATH=urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL)[0]

ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, PATH, 3)
```

> **Updated Answer:** some URLs might return `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`.

Try this instead:

```
import os
import requests
import ctypes

url = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/692713673076113461/741287055610609684/hqdefault.png'
r = requests.get(url)
name = "background_image.png"

file = open(name, "wb")
file.write(r.content)
file.close()
PATH = os.path.abspath(name)

ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, PATH, 3)
```

Comment: I can only do this, with google images right?
Cause when I use a image from discord or other sites, I get a error

Comment: Hmm, could you send the link or a similar link ? If you need authentication to get there then it might now work

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/692713673076113461/741287055610609684/hqdefault.png

Comment: @DerNoob please try my edited answer. The updated part.